# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update

Tags: php

i have this problem :

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tutoblog`.`post_category`, CONSTRAINT `fk_category` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: public function attachCategories(int $id,array $categories){
$this->pdo->exec('DELETE FROM post_category WHERE post_id = ' . $id);
$query= $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO post_category SET post_id = ?,category_id = ?');
foreach ($categories as $category){
$query->execute([$id, $category]);
}
}

Comment: public function select(string $key, string $label, array $options = []): string
{
$optionsHTML = [];
$value = $this->getValue($key);
foreach ($options as $K => $v) {
$selected = in_array($key,$value) ? " selected" : "";
$optionsHTML[] = "<option value=\"$key\"$selected>$v</option>" ;
}
$optionsHTML = implode('', $optionsHTML);
return <<<HTML
<div class="form-group">
<label for="field{$key}">{$label}</label>
<select id="field{$key}" class="{$this->getInputClass($key)}" name="{$key}[]" required multiple>{$optionsHTML}</select>
{$this->getErrorFeedback($key)}
</div>
HTML;

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert/update a table with a foreign key constraint.

The field `category_id` must be set to an id that exists in you table `category`.
So make sure you create your category first and then link it in your entry.